# dropping databases from exported sql file generated by phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have used the export function `phpmyadmin` to export one database (let's call it `db_x`) and save as sql files, normally I will drop `db_x` afterwards and create it again for storing another set of data. The exported `db_x` file is used as a backup so that I can still retrieve the data from it if needed.

But this time, I accidentally exported the entire mysql databases (let's call it `db_all`) into one sql file, including the `information_schema` and databases that `root` has no permission to drop. Now I need the data from `db_x` in `db_all`, so I try to do the import using `phpmyadmin` as usual, and it prompts that I need to drop some of the existing databases (e.g. `information_schema`) which is not possible. I am somehow stuck in the situation that I have `db_x` in `db_all`, but I cannot import it into via `phpmyadmin`.

I wonder if there is any way to "edit" the `db_all` file so that databases other than `db_a` are dropped.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you ever taken a look at one of those dumps with a texteditor? If not, you probably should.

Comment: @GhostGambler thank you, I opened the sql using text editor, and compared with my previous `db_a` file saved correctly, looks like it can be edited using text edtior.

Comment: exactly ;) You can remove all the parts of the dump you do not want to import.